# Dynamically updating db with SELECT menu

Tags: php, mysql

Thanks for all advice! I am pulling a list of months that are not set to "current month" into a drop down/select menu in order to set some other month to be available for action. I get that list but and it populates the dropdown but then doesn't pass that value to the update. I'm either super confused or missing something very small.

Here are the queries:

```
if (isset($_POST['addMonth'])) {
   $addmonth = $_POST['addmonth'];
   //open additional months
   $query_open_additional = "UPDATE reimbmonths SET reimb_open = 1 WHERE monthname = '$addmonth' ";
   $query_current = "SELECT * FROM reimbmonths WHERE reimb_open = 1";
   $result_current = mysql_query($query_current) or die ('Query failed: ' . mysql_error() . "<br />\n$sql");
   $num_current = mysql_num_rows($result_current);

   echo "Added another month: " . $addmonth;
}
```

And this is the HTML/PHP:

```
<h3>Open additional months</h3>
<form id="add-months" action="" method="post" onsubmit="window.location.reload() onchange="addMonth();"">
    <select name="addmonth" id="addmonth">
        <option <? if (empty($_POST["addmonth"])) { echo 'selected';} ?> disabled> --- Choose a Month --- </option>
        <?
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $num_months) {
            $month_to_add = mysql_result($result_select_closed,$i,"monthname");
        ?>
        <option value="<? $month_to_add ?>" <? if($_POST["addmonth"] === '$month_to_add') { echo 'selected';} ?>><? echo ucwords($month_to_add) ?></option>
        <? 
        $i++;
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input class="submit_btn" type="submit" name="addMonth" value="Set Month"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you displayed the value in `$_POST["addmonth"]`? Are you sure it is ok?

Comment: Unrelated, but `$i = 0; while ($i < $n) { ...; $i++; }` is the same as `for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) { ...; }`

Comment: You never use `$query_open_additional` anywhere.

Comment: `if($_POST["addmonth"] === '$month_to_add')`, I think triple equal is not necessary as well as the single quotes, try `if($_POST["addmonth"] == $month_to_add)`

Comment: $query_open_additional should run on submit.

Comment: Yes, when I click submit it displays what $addmonth is but the query never executes...